# How can I handle a very large database and do not miss the performance?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, full-text-search, bigdata, database

if i want to develop an application, I'm worried about its **performance** after the number of users and stored data increases.
actually I don't know what is the best way to implement a program that it works with a really large data and do some things like search in it, find and receive user information, search text and so on **in real time without any delay** !

Let's me explain the problem more

**for example** i have chosen '**Mongodb**' as a database and suppose we have at least five million users and a user want to log in into the system, the user has sent the username and password  
The first thing that we should do is to find the user with that username and then check the password, in mongodb we should use something like 'find' method to get the user's information, something like below:

```
Users.find({ username: entered_username })
```

then get the user information and we check the password 
but the 'find' method **should search** the username between **million users** and it's a large number and if any person request for authentication, this method should be run for each of them and it cause a heavy processing on the system

but unfortunately this problem is only for something like finding a user, if we decide to search a text when we have a lot of texts and posts on the database the problem is more bigger

i don't know how big companies like facebook and linkedin search through millions of data in such a short span of time. actually i don't want to create something like facebook or more but i have a large amount of data and i'm looking for a good way to handle it

is there any framework or something else that help me to handle large data on the databases or is there exist a method to implement data on database so that we search and find data fast and quickly? should i use a particular data structure?

i founded an opensource project [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) that it help us to search faster but i don't know if i found something with elastic how can i find it on mongodb too for doing something like updating data and if i use elastic search i should use mongodb too or not!? can i use elastic as a database and as a search engine simultaneous !?
if i use elasticsearch and mongodb together then i should have two copies of my data, one in mongodb and one in elasticsearch!? and this two copies of the data that are separated :( i wish elasticsearch search in the mongodb that does not have to create two copies of the data

thank you if you help me to find out a good way and understand what should i do.

Comment: First of all off question is topic. Second elasticsearch is not a database it's a search engine. And last 5000000 is not a lot of users is medium size.

Comment: i know that elasticsearch is not a database but we can use it as a database too and about the number of users i only say an example

Comment: ElasticSearch should not be used as a primary Database. LinkedIn uses elasticsearch to provide search functionality and Facebook uses Apache Cassandra but 5000000 row is nothing a well indexed SQL server should not be able to handle especially since you are doing showing find by Id and that is fast in all solutions. But there is so much out there on the topic that I don't see any point in asking this. It all depends how good you are at IT infrastructure or do you want to pay AWS or Azure to get what ever performance you want.

Comment: maybe i shouldn't said 5000000 number and just say it's a large data, i want to choose mongodb as  primary Database and use elasticsearch for searching in mongodb... but my problem is that elasticsearch can not directly search in the mongodb and i want to know should i create two copies of data in elastic and mongo or there is such a method to do this...

Comment: As I already pointed out not a SO question. But yes it is recommended to use [mongo and elastic](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/elasticsearch-mongodb-gaurhari-dass) if you plan to use ES in production. But this idea that somehow using mongo and/or elastic will magically give you performance is just false. It all depends on what are you planning to do. Most big websites use Micro services architecture so they use a little bit of everything. Stack overflow uses SqlServer and they don't have a perf problem so you can make anything slow if you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about performance, it usually boils down to three things:

- Your design
- Your definition of "quick", and
- How much you're willing to pay

#### Your design

MongoDB is great if you want to iterate on your data model, can scale horizontally, and very quick if used properly. Elasticsearch on the other hand, is not a database. However, it is very quick for searching. A traditional relational database will be useful if you know exactly how your data looks like, and don't expect it to change much, or is relational by nature.

You can, for example, use a relational database for user login, use MongoDB for everything else, and use Elastic for textual, searchable data. There is no rule that tells you to keep everything within a single database.

Make sure you understand indexing, and know how to utilize it to its fullest potential. The fastest hardware will not help you if you don't design your database properly.

Conclusion: use any tool you need, combine if necessary, but understand their strengths and weaknesses.

#### Your definition of "quick"

How "quick" is quick enough for your application? Is 100ms quick enough? Is 10ms quick enough? Remember that more performance you ask of the machine, more expensive it will be. You can get more performance with a better design, but design can only go so far.

Usually this boils down to what is acceptable for you and your client. Not every application needs a sub-10ms response time. There's plenty of applications that can tolerate queries that return in seconds.

Conclusion: determine what is acceptable, and design accordingly.

#### How much you're willing to pay

Of course, it all depends on how much you're willing to pay for all the hardware that need to host all that stuff. MongoDB might be open source, but you need some place to host it. Also, you cannot expect magic. You can't throw thousands of queries and updates per second, and expect it to be blazing fast when you only give it 1 GB of RAM.

Conclusion: never under-provision to save money if you want your application to be successful.

Comment: thank you Kevin for answer. i have a question about the first part (design), is it a good way to store all textual and searchable data in elastic and isn't necessary to store that data in mongodb too? i think it means we are using elastic as a database for a part of our data, like textual data! but you and others are saying elastic isn't a database and we shouldn't use elasticsearch as a database and it is just an engine, so we should have another copy our data in another database like mongodb...

Comment: but i am confusing here if we store data in elastic and we find something by it if we have a copy of that data in mongodb too if we want to edit something we should find that data in mongodb too... and here what is the benefit of elastic??

Comment: we are using mongodb for search too, and elastic just find data in it's own storage, i wanna search data in mongodb by elastic not search in elastic's data

Comment: Design is the trickiest part. What I'm trying to say is that you may be able to split your data into multiple sections, but instead of storing them in separate tables or collections, store them in separate databases instead. Of course this depends heavily on your understanding of each tech, since this will make the system considerably more complex and harder to maintain.

Comment: I would suggest that you start with the tech you're most familiar with at first, and create a working application. Sure you should think about scale, but thinking about extreme scaling at this point is premature optimization. For example, I would argue that Rails is not that scalable. However, a great many popular website use it without any issue. Get your project off the ground first, then scale out with different tech when it's required.